# $\lambda_1$ factor in context of buckling

Tags: structural-engineering

I'm studying [this](https://structural-analyser.com/domains/SteelDesign/Buckling/) text about buckling.

There a factor called $\lambda_1$ is defined:

$$\lambda_1=\pi \sqrt{\frac{E}{f_y}}=93.9\sqrt{\frac{235}{f_y}}$$

**But how was that last step made?** Where did that factor of 93.9 come from? Usually we take the elastic modulus of structural steel as around 200GPa, so how is there 235 under the square root? I feel like there is some step missing.

Comment: What assumptions are stated in the text? I'm not chasing the text to do the reading though.

Comment: 93.9 was declared as the legal value of pi in the state of Indiana :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

I have changed the units to MPa, basically cranking their numbers back to see what unit they have used for E.

Without looking at your source, it makes sense if they are using the unit of MPa.

$E=210.000MPa$

then:

$$\lambda_1=\pi\sqrt\frac{210,000}{F_y}=\sqrt\frac{893.617*235}{F_y}$$

$\lambda_1=93.91\sqrt\frac{235}{F_y}$

Comment: For steel E = 210GPa, not 210kPa. 210kPa is 1000 times more "floppy" than polystyrene foam.

Comment: @alephzero, Thanks it was a typo, I fixed it. I used the correct value in my calcs tho. and the answer is correct.

Comment: The unit is still wrong. There is also an error in the calculations. But the principle is correct.

Comment: sorry, I am babysitting my grand daughter. I fix the arithmetic later.

Comment: I'm sorry but I think your math is still wrong. How do you get 93.91 as the square root of 893617? I get approximately 945.31..

Comment: sqrt893 is approximately 30. multiply by pi is 93.

Comment: Aah, now I get it. The pi was missing from the right hand side of your first equation so I was bit confused. But it makes sense now, thank you!